# Changed job whilst still in the interview process with another company

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, new-job

What is the best way to update the company that I'm interviewing that I've changed positions but I'm still interested?

Additional information:

Company A that I'm interviewing with is my first choice however they have a long drawn out interview process 3 stages in total, this has taken months so far.

I've recently joined company B for around a month. I accepted it as it was a software engineering position and provide a decent pay rise from what I was on before.

I assumed I didn't get the position with company A after not hearing from them for some time, I could only have delayed the acceptance from A for so long.

However I was called for a second stage recently and I've cleared it. I would like to infrom company A that my circumstances have changed but I'm slightly concerned it may hinder my chances.

The reason I'm interested in company A is because they pay $12,500 more than B, a step up in seniority as well as it also being a prestigious company.

Answer (score 1):

**You should be careful.**

While your decision to join company **B** certainly makes sense given your situation (some companies just take too damn long to get back to you), **you have made a commitment** to **B** that you will work for them for the **Foreseeable future***. Of course, you're free to drop them and join company **A**, however you should take into account the following:

- This will likely burn bridges with **B** since you've basically dumped them and likely wasted their time and money (on-boarding, training, background checks, missed out on viable candidates, etc.)
- **A** will be more wary of hiring you, since you're showing them that you're flighty.

But to answer your question: If you really want to work for **A**, you should contact the hiring manager and explain that you've taken another job, and that you have to make good on your commitment to **B**, but are still interested. They will likely see this as a sign of maturity, and would make you a more attractive candidate.

However, *there is no way to protect your reputation* if you choose to join a company and then leave it for another position so soon. If **B** isn't a good fit that may be another story, however be prepared to explain why.

---

***Forseeable Future** is of course a relative time based on your job field's discretion, but for Software Engineering (my profession) I would say you should try to stick with a place for long enough to at least pay them back on their investment - say, 6 months minimum.